# How to generate symbolic variables in a for loop using Sympy (Python)

Tags: python, loops, variables, symbols, sympy

Depending on the input of my tool I need multiple variables: `A_n`, `B_n`, `C_n` and `D_n` for `n` (integer) in range `[1, x]` to formulate `x` equation of the following form:

```
W(z) = A_n*cosh(beta*z) + B_n*sinh(beta*z) + C_n*cos(beta*z) + D_n*sin(beta*z)
```

I'm using Sympy, and I cannot find a way to replace `n` for the integer in range `[1, x]` and use that symbol (`A1`, `A2`, `B1`, `B2`, etc.) in a loop (to generate the symbol or for further calculations.

How can I write or call these variables conveniently in a for loop, such that I don't have to write it by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use functions with integer arguments to represent your constants or indexed variables. Here is a toy example:

```
>>> A,B,C = symbols('A:C', cls=Function)
>>> eq = A(i)*x + B(i)*y + C(i)
>>> [eq.subs(i,j) for j in range(2)]
[x*A(0) + y*B(0) + C(0), x*A(1) + y*B(1) + C(1)]
```

Those functions can be replaced with values when you known them.

Instead of using these functions you could used Indexed, too:

```
>>> Ai=Indexed('A',i)
>>> Ai
A[i]
>>> _.subs(i,0)
A[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example of creating sympy variables/symbols with a for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUavx.png)

I just came up against this problem (sorry my answer didn't come sooner) and after an hour of trying things this is what I came out to.
I have imported sympy as **sm** by the way.
I use the globals argument to convert the strings into legal variable names, and then I can make strings with the right indices by forcing i and j to become strings.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32242299)